# making a new folder using php code

Tags: php

I just wanna ask, what is the code needed in my code in order this warning will not show

> Warning: mkdir() [function.mkdir]: File exists in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\php-robert\dir\dir.php

also did my program is correct? what i want in my program is, if the folder is not exist, make a folder, if its existing just do nothing.. nothing to show, just nothing

**dir.php**

```php
<?php
$var = "MyFolder";
$structure = "../../file/rep/$var";

if (!mkdir($structure, 0700)) {

}
else
{
echo"folder created";
}

?>
```

Comment: why not check to see if it exists first?  file_exists is the function, I believe.

Comment: The other good one to use is is_dir()

Comment: "File exists" what could that mean ?

Comment: @Dagon Think File exists warning is always show when the folder is existing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (!is_dir($structure)) {
  mkdir($structure);
}
else
{
  echo "folder already exists";
}
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in C:\xampp\htdocs\php-robert\dir\dir.php

Comment: missing a closing bracket before the first brace

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
$folder = "folder_name";
// if folder does not exist or the name is used, just not for a folder
if (!file_exists($folder) || !is_dir($folder)) {
    if (mkdir($folder, 0755)) {
        echo 'Folder created';
    } else {
        echo 'Unable to create folder';
    }
}
```

Comment: `!file_exists($folder)` meaning of this NOT EXISTING?

Comment: Yes, that means: [ if the file/folder does NOT exist ]. It does not know how to differentiate between folders and files however, that is why the second clause in the `IF` statement is used.

Comment: Sir Burmat file/folder because of this `file_exists`(for the file) and this for the folder `is_dir` thx sir

Comment: `file_exists()` works for both files AND directories.  Read the documentation for more information: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php . Also, the `0755` represents the directory permissions for the directory you are creating.  `0755` will apply the following to your directory: `rwxr-xr-x`.  Check the documentation for `mkdir` for more information also: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php

Answer (score 1):

```
if (is_dir($structure) == false and mkdir($structure, 0700) == false)
{
  echo "error creating folder";
}
else
{
  echo "folder exists or was created";
}
```

You could also test if a file exists, but it isn't a folder

Comment: its working but can u explain this line `is_dir($structure) == false and !mkdir($structure, 0700)` thx

Comment: First the directory is checked to see that it doesn't exist, then mkdir() is executed, however if mkdir() returns false (ie failure) then it will echo the error in the first statement. otherwise it continues to say that the directory either existed (when is_dir() first returns true) or mkdir didn't fail (meaning the directory was created). Basically the control structure skips trying to make the directory if it already exists, because if the first part fails, the second isn't executed in PHP due to the "AND"